# Excel pivot: count of items across multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I thought this would be easy but I'm really struggling.

I have items across different columns and I need a count of **all** the items across each column.

**Data:**

[image]

**Desired Pivot Table:**

[image]

What I'm trying is this, but it doesn't show the values from the other columns and the counts for each column aren't right.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're not considering Test number (1,2,3,4,5) on your final output, just use test and color. I copied each column and pasted to build the cells below. The table names I just copied one cell, then pasted while selecting multiple cells. It does alter your original data, but it is sometimes faster to just re-arrange your data.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Same approach as 'Sun', however you keep the test data as they are and unpivot them with the free Microsoft Excel add-In [Power Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Microsoft-Power-Query-for-Excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605) (from Excel 2010). In this way you can keep your data source as it is and transform it quickly.

Having the data in a tabular form is a good practice for building flexible pivot table.
Having the following table structure, allow you to make the pivot you want.

```
Test no.    Test Attribute    Value
```

To make the transformation (actually you unpivot your data) follow the description on the [MS Website](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Unpivot-columns-Power-Query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE&fromAR=1).

1. Import the data in Power Query (Ribbon Power Query -> from Table, cursor must be somewhere in your data)
2. Select the first column (test), on the Ribbon Transform, click on Unpivot Columns > Unpivot Other Columns

   [image]
3. Close and load to Excel (Ribbon Home)

You will get this list as data source for the pivot table:

[image]

Here the script generated from the Power Query UI.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tabelle1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Test", Int64.Type}, {"Test A", type text}, {"Test B", type text}, {"Test C", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Test"}, "Attribute", "Value")
in
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns"
```

The pivot table is then based on the new list:

- ROWS = Value
- COLUMN = Attribute
- VALUES = Attribute (count)